# Formula of the probability of two dependent events

Tags: probability, statistics, education, independence

I'm wondering if there is a formula for the probability of two dependent events $A$ and $B$.

I know that if they are independent, the formula is:

$$
P(A \cap B) = P(A) \, P(B)
$$

maybe if they are dependent there is an extra term?

Comment: In general, $\Pr(A \cap B) = \Pr(A)\Pr(B \mid A) = \Pr(B)\Pr(A \mid B)$.

Comment: Hello @N.F.Taussig great answer!

Comment: 1st event is always independent. Say, taking out 2 red balls from a box containing 10 balls(2 red, 8 blue). Taking out 1st ball is independent event. 2/10 =P(Event1) ; But now, probability of taking out 2nd red ball is affected. So event2 depends on event1, thus we take P(Event2|Event1) =1/9(probab of event2 given that event1 has occured);  instead of P(Event2) which is 2/10 if it had occured  independently. The formula for independent events comes from here too, where we say Event1 has occured, but it did not affect event2, thus P(Event2|Event1)=P(Event2) for indep events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general rule for decomposition of joint events using [conditional probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability) is:

$$\mathbb{P}(A \cap B) = \mathbb{P}(B|A) \mathbb{P}(A) = \mathbb{P}(A|B) \mathbb{P}(B).$$

Comment: Hello @Ben can you take a look at this question please? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4358302/name-of-the-formula-used-to-get-the-moments-of-a-random-vector