# Name of the formula used to get the moments of a random vector

Tags: probability, random-variables, expected-value, education, density-function

I'm lloking for the name of the following formula used to get the moments of a random vector ($j \in \lbrace 1,...,n \rbrace$; $ k_1,...,k_j \in \lbrace 1,...,n \rbrace $; $r_1,...r_j \in \mathbb{N}$).

[image]

Comment: That is more or less a definition.

Comment: It looks to me like the definition of an expected value, no?

Comment: Hello @Thomas can you post a webpage (Wiki, mathworld other) where I can read its  name please?

Comment: Maybe the others have some idea. You can have a look here for some related terminology https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/191318/example-of-computing-the-expectation-of-a-discrete-rv-using-riemann-stieltjes-in

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Contrary to popular belief, this is not a definition; it is the [law of the unconscious statistician](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician), with the expectation written in [Riemann-Stieltjes form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Stieltjes_integral).  There is a slight error in your formula, since you have too many differentials.  What you should have is the following.  Define the function $g$ by:

$$g(\mathbf{x}) = x_{k_j}^{r_1} \cdots x_{k_j}^{r_k}.$$

Then using the law of the unconscious statistician you have:

$$\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}(g(\mathbf{X})) 
&= \int \cdots \int g(\mathbf{x}) \ dF_\mathbf{X}(\mathbf{x}) \\[6pt]
&= \int \cdots \int x_{k_j}^{r_1} \cdots x_{k_j}^{r_k} \ dF_\mathbf{X}(\mathbf{x}). \\[6pt]
\end{align}$$

Comment: Hi @Ben thank you for your answer. I have some difficult to put together these informations to get the above formula; can you show some step please?

Comment: @Ben perfect explanation as usual

Comment: In my opinion this is "more or less" a definition, in the sense that definitions are done exactly so that these formulas are true.

Comment: That's true of every formula in mathematics --- they all follow by logical deduction from the definitions of the objects.

Comment: Maybe it is the concept of "equivalent definitions" that I had in mind... but ok leave it, it would be too long to discuss this... :)

Comment: Hi @Ben if possible can you see the following question about the name of a minimization please? https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/564719/name-of-the-following-minimization-ex-c2-varx-ex-c2-with

Answer (score 0):

Food for thought/discussion.

Let $X$ be a r.v. and $G=X^r$. We have the identity:

$E[G]=\int dF_{X}(x) x^r$ [1]

and:

$E[G]=\int dF_{G}(g) g$ [2]

Usually the equality between the two is referred as LOTUS, and comes from a change of variables.

But now what is the definition of $E[X^r]$? [1] or [2]? According to me [1] is the definition, because it is closer to what one would think from measure theory $\int_{\Omega} f(\omega) dP(\omega)$..

The "LOTUS theorem" than would be that we can evaluate [1] either from the definition, or from the image measure of $G$ (second formula), getting the same result.

Do you see it an other way?